# Limit exists on each set but not the union.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

We learn that if the limit of a function $f$ is $L$ on sets $X_1,X_2,\dots X_n$ then the limit is still $L$ on the union of those $X's$ (proof done by minimum $\delta$ argument). We are told this won't hold on infinitely many sets, and I was wondering what the counterexample was.

Comment: Let $ f= sin(1/x)$ defined on $R\{0}$, take sequences $Y_1,Y_2,...$ as follows, $Y_i=(y(i,j))$ where $y(i,j)=1/(2 \pi j) $ when $i \neq j$, $y(i,j)=1/(\pi/2+(2 \pi j)) $ when $i=j$, then when these sequence are treated as sets, their union, which also has $ 0$ as its cluster point, will not converges to  $ 0$.

Comment: sorry what are your sets for which the limits exist??

Comment: $$ X_i= \{  \dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi i} \} \cup \{ 1/ (2\pi j)  \mid j\in \mathbb N \} $$ . Then $f$ on each set $X_i$ will converge to $0$. But union of these sets can be viewed as $$\{  \dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi i}  \mid i\in \mathbb N \} \cup \{1/( 2\pi j)  \mid j\in \mathbb N \} $$. Hence limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = 1$ for $x\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise. For $X_k = \{ -1/k \} \cup \{ 1/m \mid m\in \mathbb N \}$. Then, $f$ converges to $1$ at $0$ on each $X_k$. But, on the union $f$ does not converge at $0$.